# Frobenius coin problem variation

Tags: number-theory

Suppose you are give $n$ currency notes from $k$ to $k+n$

i.e $k, k+1,k+2.....k+n$

Where $k,n>0$

It's asked the total number of denomination of money that can't be formed using any number of these notes.

My approch.

I can solve this when n=1. Ans is k*(k-1)/2
But
 How should i approach when n ≥1?

**______**
Source: https://www.codechef.com/JUNE19B/problems/CHFING

Comment: Shouldn't it be from k to k+n-1? If it's from k to k+n you would have n+1 different notes.

Comment: @Kruga, good point. In my solution I assume OP meant "(n+1) currency notes".

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer

> It is obvious that if $ k = 1 $ any amount of money can be formed.
>
>  If $n \geqslant (k-1)$ any amount of money greater or equal then $k$ can be formed. So the answer is
>
>  $k-1$
>
>  From now on we will only consider the case of
>
>  $ k > 1$ and $ n < (k - 1) $
>
>  Let
>
>  $q = \lfloor \frac{(k - 1)}{n} \rfloor $
>
>  Then the number of the amounts of money that cannot be formed is
>
>  $(q + 1)(k - 1 - \frac{nq}{2})$

Reasoning:

> Any amount of money $x$ can be uniquely represented as
>
>  $x = pk + r$ where $ 0 \leqslant r \leqslant (k - 1)$
>
>  It is not difficult to observe that $x$ cannot be formed iff
>
>  $np < r$
>
>  If $np \geqslant r$ we can always start with $p$ bills of value $k$ and then keep increasing each of them until we reach $x$.
>
>  Now we can calculate the total by adding all amounts that cannot be formed for every value of $p$ from $0$ to $q$
>
>  $p = 0:$   $(k-1)$
>  $p = 1:$   $(k-1) - n$
>  $p = 2:$   $(k-1) - 2n$
>  $...$
>  $p = q:$   $(k-1) - qn$
>
>  Summing this sequence up for all values of $p$ gives us the formula:
>
>   $(q + 1)(k - 1 - \frac{nq}{2})$